# Opening WordPress files linking to another domain that is a nextjs application

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, pdf, next.js

An nextjs application sits on site `www.yyy.com`, for example. A WordPress site hosted at `www.zzz.com` (or `www.yyy-subdomain.com`?), if I upload a PDF to that WordPress site, can it be opened via `www.yyy.com/path-to-pdf` on the nextjs domain without adjusting any code? Just by pointing it there, or would it somewhat have to be stored on nextjs application (either by fetching file via url in wordpress)

Comment: Can't be done exactly the way you've described. But what you can do is you can create a page or API in nextjs and pass the param of the filename which you're looking then you can send a request to the WordPress domain and fetch the file content or do something else. As you didn't described the use of file so I can't really tell you much ahead.

Comment: yeah had that in mind, thanks for confirming. The domain part confused me, need to get more clued up in that respect. Cheers!